# How to create a columnar report in Visual Studio 2008 - Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crosstab

I'm trying to summarize data in a crystal report. I'd like to create a columnar view of data in crystal but am not sure how to do it. I was wanting to use a crosstab but when I try to insert, the control never appears. I create a crosstab report but when done, it comes to a blank report. I want it to be like [this](http://img123.imageshack.us/my.php?image=61519307xx5.jpg) except columns would be vehicleCategory and rows would be individual charges

1 - Any idea what I'm doing wrong and
2 - is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going for the Necromancer badge again. :)

You should be able to open the Cross-Tab expert, and put vehicleCategory as the columns, individual rows would be the individual charges and the summarized fields would be what ever you want to sum for (ie. Count of vehicleCategory). On the custom style tab make sure that you aren't suppressing the grand totals until you make sure that you are showing data. Also make sure that you are suppressing or hiding the section that you are putting the cross tab in.

I'm sure you are well past this issue now, but I figured I'd throw an answer out there for you  so that if nothing else I can try for a new badge. :)